# Meteor JS - $sort not working when new post added

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sorting, meteor

I have a collection of posts, each have an ISO timestamp (ex: "2014-08-11T16:34:39.334Z"). I'd like to sort the posts by timestamp descending.

When I load the page the first time, everything works fine. Posts are ordered by timestamp descending.

However, when I add a new post, the new post gets appended to the end of the list, instead of appearing at the top, as it should (since its timestamp is the most recent).

I have the $sort setup on my router to sort by timestamp descending "-1".

The template is definitely "reacting" by adding the new post, but not in the right order.

**router.js**

```
this.route('profile',{
  path:'/profile',
  waitOn:function(){
    Session.set('profile',this.params.username);
    return Meteor.subscribe('postsByOwner',this.params.username);
  },
  data:{
    user:function(){
      var username = Session.get("profile");
      var user = Meteor.users.findOne({username:username});
      if(user){
        return user;
      }
    },
    posts:function(){
      return Posts.find({},{$sort:{timestamp:-1}});
    }
  }
});
```

**profile.html**

```
<template name="profile">
  {{#if user}}
    {{> profileCard user}}
  {{/if}}
  {{#if posts.count}}
    {{> postsList}}
  {{else}}
    No posts!
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

**methods.js**

```
savePost: function(fields) {
  var user = Meteor.user();
  if (!user)
    throw new Meteor.Error(401, "You need to login to post!");

  var d = new Date();
  var timestamp = d.toISOString();

  var post = _.extend(_.pick(fields, 'title', 'description'), {
    owner: user._id,
    timestamp : timestamp
  });

  postId = Posts.insert(post);
}
```

Comment: Wrong syntax, use "sort" not "$sort".

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick feedback. I tried that, but still getting the same results. Only after a hard refresh will the posts be sorted correctly.

Comment: Could you show how you are inserting `Posts` and update `sort` if that doesn't fix it?

Comment: Hi Neil - I added the method code snippet above. What do you mean by "update sort"?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is `sort`, not `$sort`. Next, the fact that the sorting works only after a hard refresh tells me that you are adding to the `posts` collection on the client before it reaches the server via Meteor's stubbing. You can avoid this by re-subscribing in an `autorun` function inside `Template.profile.onCreated` everytime a new post is added.

Now my opinion: you should store the UNIX timestamp. Since the UNIX timestamp is the number of milliseconds since UNIX epoch, sorting it is definitive.

If you use `moment.js`, you can simply do `moment().valueOf()` to get the current timestamp:

```
  var post = _.extend(_.pick(fields, 'title', 'description'), {
    owner: user._id,
    timestamp : moment().valueOf();
  });
```

If you want to use vanilla JavaScript:

```
  var post = _.extend(_.pick(fields, 'title', 'description'), {
    owner: user._id,
    timestamp : new Date().getTime();
  });
```

You can easily convert the UNIX timestamp to other formats, e.g.

```
moment(unixTimeStamp).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

[ref](http://momentjs.com/docs/)